# Auto-commenting ending braces in Emacs C-mode

Tags: c, emacs

At one point in time I was running Emacs with an option which auto-commented ending braces with the label for the block they were closing (function name, if (condition), etc). I have since lost said option, and have spent several days searching for it.  Is anyone familiar with an option, minor mode, or elisp snippet that accomplishes this task?

Comment: IIRC, it was with older versions of Emacs when electric mode was enabled.  Not sure if new ones have that function.  I couldn't recall the version of Emacs that had it.  Which version were you using when you last used the function/feature?

Answer (score 0):

[Verilog mode](http://www.veripool.org/ftp/verilog-mode.el) does this. I'm not familiar with Lisp, but as far as I understood the code the *magic* is done in `verilog-label-be`.